# Get data from past 24 hours, past week, etc

Tags: ios, arrays, date, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a function in an app that will let the user pick a time frame like past 24 hours or past week and see results that only go back that far. I've tried so many things that I'm not even sure what I'm doing anymore and I'd like some help.

```
PFQuery *dateQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"NewMarcoPolo"];
[dateQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThan:yesterday];
[dateQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
       //NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
           // NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        }
    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", dateQuery);
}];
```

I'm also not sure how to know if it works or not. I tried logging it in the console but as an array I only get `PFQuery: 0x9b55030`. If anyone has an idea how to get my desired results I'd be very grateful. And if anyone has tips for how to implement this, it'd be great.

Comment: You get results in the `NSArray` objects, not the dateQuery. Uncomment the `// NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);` line and see the output. Also double check your yesterday variable.

Comment: It doesn't log to anything. And my yesterday value is a time interval `NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;` and then I did a negative of that. `NSDate *yesterday = [[NSDate alloc]initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:secondsPerDay * -1];
` was this wrong?

Comment: To debug, I would also uncomment this line: `//NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);` and skip the second line where you filter the data. First, make sure you get all data and you can log them. If that works, your problem is on the second line.

Comment: Okay that did work. Can you give me a tip to get that to work? I've searched around for hours and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Try this yesterday: `NSDate *yesterday = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60*24];`

Comment: Even your yesterday looks ok. I would list all objects and their createdAt attributes to see when they've been created: `NSLog(@"%@", object.createdAt);`. How many do you see and what date creations you see?

Comment: in the findObjectsInBackground block your are print the query thats the reason why its displaying PFQuery: 0x9b55030,in the for loop uncomment NSLog(@"%@",object.objectId) and check tour result